# Python Windows service tray icon not shown

Tags: python, windows, windows-services, pywin32, win32gui

I wrote a basic Python script with help socketserver. Then, wrapped it with code to work as a Windows service and add a function for tray icon.
Install script as service. When I run it like this:

```
test.py debug
```

Service starts, working perfectly, and most important, icon appears in tray.

But when I run:

```
test.py start
```

Script wouldn't start. If run through console MMC, the following message appears:

[image: screenshot of service stopped message]

with no addition info.

After spending some time doing code research, I found what this row is guilty in `show()` method:

```
win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_ADD, nid)
```

TrayIcon function:

```
class Taskbar:

    icoimage = None
    hinst =  win32api.GetModuleHandle(None)

    def __init__(self):
        self.visible = 0
        message_map = {
            win32con.WM_DESTROY: self.onDestroy,
            win32con.WM_USER+20 : self.onTaskbarNotify,
        }
        # Register the Window class.
        wc = win32gui.WNDCLASS()
        hinst = wc.hInstance = win32api.GetModuleHandle(None)
        wc.lpszClassName = "PythonTaskbarDemo"
        wc.style = win32con.CS_VREDRAW | win32con.CS_HREDRAW;
        wc.hCursor = win32gui.LoadCursor( 0, win32con.IDC_ARROW )
        wc.hbrBackground = win32con.COLOR_WINDOW
        wc.lpfnWndProc = message_map # could also specify a wndproc.
        classAtom = win32gui.RegisterClass(wc)
        # Create the Window.
        style = win32con.WS_OVERLAPPED | win32con.WS_SYSMENU
        self.hwnd = win32gui.CreateWindow( classAtom, "Taskbar Demo", style, \
                    0, 0, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, \
                    0, 0, hinst, None)
        win32gui.UpdateWindow(self.hwnd)

    def setIcon(self, hicon, tooltip=None):
        self.hicon = hicon
        self.tooltip = tooltip

    def show(self):
        """Display the taskbar icon"""
        flags = win32gui.NIF_ICON | win32gui.NIF_MESSAGE
        if self.tooltip is not None:
            flags = win32gui.NIF_TIP
            nid = (self.hwnd, 0, flags, win32con.WM_USER+20, self.hicon, self.tooltip)
        else:
            nid = (self.hwnd, 0, flags, win32con.WM_USER+20, self.hicon)
        if self.visible:
            self.hide()

        win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_ADD, nid)
        self.visible = 1

    def hide(self):
        """Hide the taskbar icon"""
        if self.visible:
            nid = (self.hwnd, 0)
            win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_DELETE, nid)
        self.visible = 0

    def onDestroy(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        self.hide()
        win32gui.PostQuitMessage(0) # Terminate the app.

    hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam = 0,0,0,0

    def onTaskbarNotify(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        self.hwnd = hwnd
        self.msg = msg
        self.wparam = wparam
        self.lparam = lparam
        return 1

    def start_tray(self):
        icon = win32gui.LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)
        self.setIcon(icon)
        self.show()
```

Comment: Windows services run in a different session (0) to user sessions and cannot interact with the user's display. There is a flag on the service to allow interact with desktop, but this is not recommended due to potential security issues. The correct way to do want you are trying is to have a process in the user session that has some IPC mechanism with the service and that can show any graphical elements and user interactions.